# jQuery Parse JSON Array

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, parsing

OK so this is driving me insane.. 
I'm attempting to parse JSON from a web method into a `<ul>`, here's what I've got:

```
function searchPostcode() {
    var search = $("#txtPostcode").attr("value");
    //alert(search);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "DeliverySettings.aspx/getDeliveryInfoForPostcode",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{'postcode':'" + search + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: AjaxSucceeded,
        error: AjaxFailed
    });

    function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
        var items = [];

        $.each(eval(result), function (key, val) {
            items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
        });

        $('<ul/>', {
            'class': 'my-new-list',
            html: items.join('')
        }).appendTo('jsonresults');

    }
    function AjaxFailed(result) {
        alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
    }
}
```

And here's a sample of the JSON returned from the WebMethod:

```
[{"Name":"Full Pallet","Price":"90.0000"},{"Name":"Half Pallet","Price":"60.0000"},{"Name":"Quarter Pallet","Price":"40.0000"},{"Name":"Small Parcel","Price":"30.0000"},{"Name":"Medium Parcel","Price":"20.0000"},{"Name":"Large Parcel","Price":"10.0000"}]
```

I've tried with and without the `eval` to no avail, I just cant get into a list... Please help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `jsonresults`? If it's an ID, you forgot the `#`

```
.appendTo('#jsonresults');
```

Also, with this:

```
items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
```

you'll get `[object Object]` as the text content. I assume you want the `Name`. If so, do this:

```
items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.Name + '</li>');
```

Also keep in mind that the `key` is the index of the Array. If you're supporting HTML4, it isn't valid to have an ID that starts with a number.

You may want to change it to:

```
items.push('<li id=product_"' + key + '">' + val.Name + '</li>');
```

...or something similar.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/G8HqX/

Comment: My bad, I was testing earlier and named the tag <jsonresults> rather than setting a class or id

Comment: Cheers for the heads up on the ID, that's sorted. val.Name gives me undefined..?

Comment: @Leigh: Have you verified that your response is arriving correctly? `console.log(result)`

Comment: ...because you have `dataType:'json'`, jQuery will get it parsed for you, so you should get rid of the `eval()`, and just do `$.each(result,...`

Comment: I removed eval and checked the log as suggested, I do get the result back as in : d: "[{"Name":"Full Pallet","Price":"90.0000"},{"Name":"Half Pallet","Price":"60.0000"},{"Name":"Quarter Pallet","Price":"40.0000"},{"Name":"Small Parcel","Price":"30.0000"},{"Name":"Medium Parcel","Price":"20.0000"},{"Name":"Large Parcel","Price":"10.0000"}]" but still I get undefined.. is the d anything to do with it?